# Values cannot be null parameter name:g

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have made two usercontrols and included that in my main usercontrol.After that I have Used that user control in one of my form but now the problem is that it's showing me an error that instance cannot be created. when I hover on my usercontrol reference in main form it's says 'Values cannot be null parameter name:g'.Usercontrol that gives error is on line 40 of windows, specifically `<pc:SearchProduct x:Name="ProductFilterResult" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>`.
Any help will be appreciated

**UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CPOSApplication.UserControls.Products.SearchProduct"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:CPOSApplication.UserControls.Products"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500" Width="Auto" Padding="5">
        <Grid  Focusable="True" x:Name="ProductGrid" Loaded="ProductGrid_Loaded">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="194" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource SearchGridHeaderBorder}">
                <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label x:Name="GridLabel" Style="{DynamicResource HeadingLabelsCustomStyle}" Content="Search Product:"/>
                    <Button x:Name="AddBtn" Style="{DynamicResource AddButtonCustomStyle}" Content="Add Product (F10)"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
            <uc:ProductFilterResult x:Name="productFilterResult" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0"/>
            <uc:FilterProduct x:Name="filterProduct" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Padding="2,0,0,0" Margin="5,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

**UserControl.CS File**

```
using BusinessLogic;
using CPOSApplication.Classes.Managers;
using CPOSApplication.Forms;
using CPOSApplication.GeneralControl;
using Models.DatabaseModels;
using Models.HelpingModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CPOSApplication.UserControls.Products
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SearchProduct.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SearchProduct : UserControl
    {
        #region[Global Properties]
        ProductSearchViewModel filters = new ProductSearchViewModel();
        MainDashboard MainWindow;
        SearchResultModel<ProductViewModel> GridList = new SearchResultModel<ProductViewModel>();
        Guid CurrentApplicationId = new Guid(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"]);
        int RecordsPerPage = 16;
        #endregion
        #region[Contructor]
        public SearchProduct()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            #region[Events Registration]
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ProductView_Loaded);
            this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ProductView_UnLoaded);
            productFilterResult.pager.PageSelected += pager_PageSelected;
            productFilterResult.Edit += Edit_Click;
            productFilterResult.Delete += Delete_Click;
            AddBtn.Click += Add_Click;
            filterProduct.FilterBtn.Click += FilterBtn_Click;
            filterProduct.ClearBtn.Click += ClearBtn_Click;
            #endregion
            #region[Search Filters]
            SetFilterParameters(null);
            #endregion
            GridList = new Logic(GetCurrentApplicationId()).GetProductsByFilter(filters);
            RefreshResultGrid(GridList, true);
        }
        #endregion
        #region[Events]
        void ProductView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow = (MainDashboard)Window.GetWindow(this);
            #region[Hotkey Events Initialization]

            HotKeyManager.RegisterMultiKeyGesture(HotActions.DeleteProductPopUp, new MultiKeyGesture(new Key[] { Key.D }, ModifierKeys.Control, "Delete"), DeleteHotKeyPressed);
            HotKeyManager.RegisterMultiKeyGesture(HotActions.EditProduct, new MultiKeyGesture(new Key[] { Key.E }, ModifierKeys.Control, "Edit"), EditHotKeyPressed);
            HotKeyManager.RegisterKey(HotActions.AddProduct, new KeyGesture(Key.F10, ModifierKeys.None), F10Pressed);
            HotKeyManager.RegisterKey(HotActions.ClearProductFilters, new KeyGesture(Key.F9, ModifierKeys.None), F9Pressed);
            HotKeyManager.RegisterKey(HotActions.SearchProductFilter, new KeyGesture(Key.F7, ModifierKeys.None), F7Pressed);
            //HotKeyManager.RegisterKey(HotActions.AddProduct, new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Shift | ModifierKeys.Control), CTRL);
            #endregion
        }
        void ProductView_UnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<HotActions> CurrentWindowActions = new List<HotActions>()
            {
                HotActions.AddProduct,
                HotActions.DeleteProductPopUp,
                HotActions.EditProduct,
                HotActions.ClearProductFilters,
                HotActions.SearchProductFilter
            };
            HotKeyManager.RemoveBindings(CurrentWindowActions);
        }
        void pager_PageSelected(GeneralControl.PaginationControl.Paginator sender, int total, int selectedPage)
        {
            filters.CurrentPage = selectedPage;
            filters.CalculateTotal = false;
            GridList = new Logic(GetCurrentApplicationId()).GetProductsByFilter(filters);
            RefreshResultGrid(GridList, false);

        }
        private void FilterBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FilterProducts();

        }
        private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClearTextBoxes(this);
        }
        private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProductViewModel Product = (ProductViewModel)(sender as Image).Tag;
            DeleteProductPopup(Product);
        }
        private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProductViewModel Product = (ProductViewModel)(sender as Image).Tag;
            UpdateProductPopup(Product);
        }
        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateProductPopup(null);
        }
        private void ProductGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProductGrid.Focus();
        }


        #endregion
        #region[HotKeys Events]
        private void F10Pressed(HotKeyBindData sender)
        {
            UpdateProductPopup(null);
        }
        private void DeleteHotKeyPressed(HotKeyBindData sender)
        {
            string PressedKeys = MultiKeyGesture.GetPressedKeys();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PressedKeys))
            {
                PressedKeys = PressedKeys.Replace("D", "");
                ProductViewModel BindedModel = null;
                var dg = productFilterResult.ProductsGrid;
                for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    var cellContent = dg.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row);
                    var cellContentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)cellContent;
                    DataTemplate editingTemplate = cellContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
                    TextBlock CellTextBox = editingTemplate.FindName("IndexCell", cellContentPresenter) as TextBlock;
                    if (CellTextBox != null)
                    {
                        string CellValue = CellTextBox.Text;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CellValue))
                        {
                            if (CellValue == PressedKeys)
                            {
                                BindedModel = (ProductViewModel)cellContentPresenter.Content;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (BindedModel != null)
                {
                    ProductViewModel model = BindedModel;
                    DeleteProductPopup(model);
                }
            }
        }
        private void EditHotKeyPressed(HotKeyBindData sender)
        {
            string PressedKeys = MultiKeyGesture.GetPressedKeys();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PressedKeys))
            {
                PressedKeys = PressedKeys.Replace("D", "");
                ProductViewModel BindedModel = null;
                var dg = productFilterResult.ProductsGrid;
                for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    var cellContent = dg.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row);
                    var cellContentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)cellContent;
                    DataTemplate editingTemplate = cellContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
                    TextBlock CellTextBox = editingTemplate.FindName("IndexCell", cellContentPresenter) as TextBlock;
                    if (CellTextBox != null)
                    {
                        string CellValue = CellTextBox.Text;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CellValue))
                        {
                            if (CellValue == PressedKeys)
                            {
                                BindedModel = (ProductViewModel)cellContentPresenter.Content;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (BindedModel != null)
                {
                    ProductViewModel model = BindedModel;
                    UpdateProductPopup(model);
                }
            }
        }

        private void F9Pressed(HotKeyBindData sender)
        {
            ClearTextBoxes(this);
        }
        private void F7Pressed(HotKeyBindData sender)
        {
            FilterProducts();
        }
        #endregion
        #region[Events Supporting Functions]
        private void RefreshResultGrid(SearchResultModel<ProductViewModel> result, bool RefrestCounter)
        {
            productFilterResult.ProductsGrid.ItemsSource = result.ResultList;
            if (RefrestCounter)
            {
                productFilterResult.pager.setCounts(result.TotalCount, filters.RecordsPerPage);
            }
        }
        private void SetFilterParameters(string ProductName)
        {
            filters.Name = ProductName;
            filters.CurrentPage = 1;
            filters.RecordsPerPage = RecordsPerPage;
            filters.CalculateTotal = true;
        }

        private void UpdateProductPopup(ProductViewModel Product)
        {
            try
            {
                MainWindow.modelPanelBG.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Window window = new Window();
                window.Content = new UpdateProduct(window, MainWindow, Product);
                window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                window.Width = 500;
                window.Height = 200;
                window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                window.AllowsTransparency = true;
                window.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
        private void DeleteProductPopup(ProductViewModel Product)
        {
            try
            {
                MainWindow.modelPanelBG.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Window window = new Window();
                window.Content = new DeleteProduct(window, MainWindow, Product);
                window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                window.Width = 300;
                window.Height = 120;
                window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                window.AllowsTransparency = true;
                bool delete = window.ShowDialog() ?? false;
                if (delete == true)
                {
                    GridList.ResultList.Remove(Product);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
        void ClearTextBoxes(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            TextBox tb = obj as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
                tb.Text = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj as DependencyObject); i++)
                ClearTextBoxes(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i));
        }
        private void FilterProducts()
        {
            SetFilterParameters(filterProduct.ProductName.Text);
            GridList = new Logic(GetCurrentApplicationId()).GetProductsByFilter(filters);
            RefreshResultGrid(GridList, true);
        }
        private Guid GetCurrentApplicationId()
        {
            string ApplicationIdConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicationIdConfig))
                return new Guid();
            else
                return new Guid(ApplicationIdConfig);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Window**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:pc="clr-namespace:CPOSApplication.UserControls.Products"
        xmlns:mpc="clr-namespace:CPOSApplication.UserControls.ModelPanelBackground"
        xmlns:muc="clr-namespace:CPOSApplication.UserControls.Menus"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="mainWindow" x:Class="CPOSApplication.Forms.MainDashboard"
        Title="CPOS" Height="720" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Icon="/CPOSApplication;component/Resources/logo.png">
    <Grid x:Name="mainDashboardForm">
        <mpc:ModelPanelBackground x:Name="modelPanelBG" Margin="0,0,0,10" Panel.ZIndex="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <DockPanel x:Name="topHeaderDockPanel" Height="50" LastChildFill="False" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#FFEEEEEE">
            <DockPanel x:Name="topLogoDockPanel" Height="40" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="10,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Image x:Name="topLogoImage" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Margin="0,7,0,5" Source="/CPOSApplication;component/Resources/logo.png"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="topRightCloseButtonDockPanel" Height="40" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,5,10,0">
                <Button x:Name="topRightCloseButton" Content="X" Style="{DynamicResource CloseBtn}" Click="topRightCloseButton_Click"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="topRightSettingDockPanel" Height="40" LastChildFill="False" Margin="0,5,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
            <DockPanel x:Name="topRightDropDownDockPanel" Height="40" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0"/>
            <DockPanel x:Name="topHeaderMenuDockPanel" Height="40" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0">
                <ToolBar x:Name="topHeaderMenuToolBar" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3,3,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF9B9B9B" Background="{x:Null}" Width="232" Style="{DynamicResource TitleToolBarStyle}">
                    <Button x:Name="topHeaderFeedbackButton" Content="Feedback" Margin="5,0" Style="{DynamicResource topHeaderButtonCustomStyle}" Height="30" Padding="4" />
                    <Button x:Name="topHeaderHelpButton" Content="Help" Margin="5,0" Style="{DynamicResource topHeaderButtonCustomStyle}" Height="30" Padding="4" />
                    <Button x:Name="topHeaderUpdateButton" Content="Update" Margin="5,0" Style="{DynamicResource topHeaderButtonCustomStyle}" Height="30" Padding="4"/>
                </ToolBar>
            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="topMainMenuHeader" Height="110" DockPanel.Dock="Top" LastChildFill="False" Background="#FFDAD9D9">
                <muc:UserMenu x:Name="UserMenu" Margin="0"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="bottomStatusDockPanel" Height="28" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="#FFEEEEEE">
            <Label x:Name="bottomStatusLabel" Content="Status:" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#FFAEABAB" Padding="5,6,5,5"/>
                <Label x:Name="bottomStatusContent" Content="" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#FFAEABAB" Padding="5,6,5,5"/>
            </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel x:Name="middleContentAreaDockPanel" Margin="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <pc:SearchProduct x:Name="ProductFilterResult" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: is your UserControls.Products initialized?

Comment: Do you have a default constructor for SearchProduct? As in `public SearchProduct()`.  Also, check `productFilterResult` and `filterProduct`.  Are there bindings in those that are null at compile-time, but are initialized at some point during run-time?

Comment: @NETscape yes I have a default constructor

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you don't use single letter parameters.  That g could be in any method anywhere.  This is an absolute pain to track down.

Comment: @MattBecker in case you need it in the future, the g here is likely referring to the parameter passed to the new Guid() constructor, the parameter is "string g"

Comment: In my case it was missing config entry and trying to create Guid from null value

Answer (score 6):

I'm a few years late on this answer, but hopefully this will save someone the time it takes to track it down.

Your code calls the Guid constructor with values from the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.  This can return a null value if it's not found and especially happens at design time.

Check the following two lines and be sure that the ConfigurationManager is providing non-null strings.

```
return new Guid(ApplicationIdConfig);

Guid CurrentApplicationId = new Guid(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Matt said the problem is with the Guid constructor when you have a null string or byte array as the input. 
Here you have an example:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/g7KN67